# editor works in admin page but for front-end in console I get error because of setting content to froalafield

Tags: javascript, django, froala

I'm using django-froala editor https://github.com/froala/django-froala-editor and It works fine in admin page but I get error when I try to use outside of admin page.

I get

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).froalaEditor is not a function.

It's coming from

```
$(function(){
       $('#id_content').froalaEditor({"fileUpload": false, 
                                      "inlineMode": false, "imageUpload": false})
       });
```

which I didn't write since it's 3rd party app. the error is occuring because `$()` isn't put at the end but I have no where to fix this since I'm just using it as 3rd party app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don' think it's error with the code as you stated. You have similar code in your admin (I use froala too), and it works.

Have you imported the froala editor js file in your frontend?

Comment: no I didn't import any froala js file, did you do that and it worked?

Comment: I  was just giving up on froala, will you tell me how you implemented it?for the front-end?

Comment: Check the section on using Froala outside of admin - https://github.com/froala/django-froala-editor#usage-outside-admin